# specify SAS Cfg file in SAS program

Tags: sas, remote-access, remote-server

Is there a way to specify an alternate SAS cfg file location in the SAS program ? 
or how can we have our own configuration file when running SAS remotely on a server(linux) with rsubmit.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly specify a configuration file when SAS starts up; the `-CONFIG` option allows you to do so.

When you're connecting with SAS/CONNECT, and you use a connection script, then this is fairly easy to do.  For example, one of the standard ones that you may be using is "TCPUNIX.SCR", which a sample of which is stored in [SAS Home]\connect\saslink\ .  It is responsible for starting SAS on the remote server when you issue a `connect to` command (which is what RSUBMIT later connects to).

It has a line like so:

```
type 'sas -dmr -comamid tcp -noterminal -nosyntaxcheck' LF;
```

That is a simple command-line invocation of SAS, to which you can add custom details to including configuration file location.

See the [SAS\Connect Documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000269859.htm) for more information.

When you're using the SAS/CONNECT spawner to set your connections up, you have the option `-SASCMD`, whereby you can pass startup options among other things to SAS.  See the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/67933/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0qxop2ou79cc3n1mo57cu3lrc1n.htm) for more details.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply., however I am now using a SAS Spawner connection and not telnet, this SAS spawner connection dowsnot use the TCPunix file. 
it has a Spawner script on the server side instead.

Comment: @user3658367 Then it sounds like you know who you should talk to - your server admin?  Also, please add this information to the question as it would be helpful to get correct/useful answers.